# Selecting a date in the datepicker also clicks the button behind the window

Tags: javascript

[image]

The date is selected and the datepicker is closed, followed by a button being pressed.

`const prevDate = new tui.DatePicker('#prevDate', {
language: 'ko',
type: 'date',
usageStatistics: false,
input: {
element: '#prevDate-input',
format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
}
});

```
const nextDate = new tui.DatePicker('#nextDate', {
    language: 'ko',
    type: 'date',
    usageStatistics: false,
    input: {
        element: '#nextDate-input',
        format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
    }
});`
```

I solved it with this, please let me know if there is a better way

```
const calendarBodyInners = document.querySelectorAll('.tui-calendar');
calendarBodyInners.forEach(function(calendarBodyInner) {
    calendarBodyInner.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: This isn't jquery ui datepicker.

Comment: sorry i didn't know

Comment: your solution is the correct way.